# Is there an data type that acts both as a list and a dictionary?

Tags: c#

Normally when I need to have a list of ints/strings/etc. I create a list like:

```
var list = new List<string>
```

And then I create a hashtable that contains all the strings, and I don't insert into the list unless it isn't in the hashtable i.e. to enforce unique items in the list.

Is there a datatype that can satisfy both of these requirements for me?

Comment: So... I don't get it. Do you want a set of key-value pairs in which everything must be unique, or a set of unique values?

Comment: Can you please explain what the two requirements are? I am a bit slow today.

Comment: or maybe a Dictionary<string, List<int>>?

Comment: Aren't keys in a hashtable already unique, for their unique hash code?

Comment: @Yam Marcovic: but not the values

Comment: You could also override the Add / Insert functions of the generic list<type> to perform a binary search before adding. This would give you the added benefit of sorted order and lightning fast searches with a few lines of code: `int index = list.BinarySearch(item); if (index < 0) list.Insert(~index, item)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is. Use [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx):

```
var set = new HashSet<int>();
set.Add(4);
set.Add(4);   // there is already such an element in the set, no new elements added
```

Keep in mind, though, that it does not guarantee you the order of elements.

Comment: order is not important, just uniqueness.  Does it come with a built in way for iterating (unlike the hashtable).

Comment: yes; given the sample above:
    foreach (var elem in set) {
        Console.WriteLine(elem);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Do you just mean `HashSet<string>` ?

All elements in a `HashSet<T>` are unique; the `Add()` method returns a `bool` to indicate if a new item was actually added, or whether it was a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a datatype that can satisfy both of these requirements for me?

No. A hashtable will provide you a direct access to an element given its unique key, whereas in a list you don't need a key and you could definitely have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HashSet<T>` data type [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). Which will only allow you to have a single copy of each value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after a set of unique values only (and don't subsequently care about ordering) then you should look at a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

Comment: Woops, a little slow by me! Great minds think alike. Just to highlight that the HashSet as opposed to your list/dictionary approach will not allow ordered iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx). However, this is an *old* non-updated (non-generic) class and I would generally recommend avoiding it ;-)

> > Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are accessible by the key or index.

In practice I would create a minimal wrapper class that exposes the required operations. (I would likely use a `HashSet<T>` (for existence) and a `List<T>` (for ordering), although just a single `List<T>` is far than sufficient for a relatively small `n` in most cases -- remember Big-O is about limits.)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();

bool inserted = set.Add("Item");
bool insertedDuplicate = set.Add("Item");

inserted.Dump("Result1");
insertedDuplicate.Dump("Result2");

//Result
//Result1 = true
//Result2 = false
```

You can run this in LinqPad to see the functionality and how it works.